# Syntax error on tokens, ; expected?

Tags: java

I commented all my errors in my program. The point of my program is to shift my input file by 
whatever the user inputs. My errors that I commented out are kind of pointless to me because it all make sense and the computer is not reading it the way I want it to. Not to be confused with one of the errors that I commented one of the tokens is ",". The others are "(", and ")". These all are errors that expect a semi colon somewhere in the line where I commented them.

Here is what the program looks like:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class CaesarCipher
{
 public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
 {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("What shift should I use? ");
  int shift = keyboard.nextInt();
  System.out.println("What is the name of the input file? ");
  String name = keyboard.next();
  File f = new File(name);
  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(f);
  System.out.println("What is the name of the output file? ");
  String text = keyboard.nextLine();
  PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(text);
  String encrypted = "";

  while (inFile.hasNextLine())
  {
     String line = inFile.nextLine();
      if ( shift == 1)
     encrypted = caesarEncipher(line, shift);
      else if (shift == 2)
     encrypted = caesarDecipher(line, shift);// the method caesarDecipher(java.lang.String, int) is undefined for the type CaesarCipher
      System.out.println(encrypted);
      outFile.println(encrypted);
  }
 }
  static String caesarEncipher(String text ,int shift) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
   String t = "";
   int i = 0;
   while (i < t.length())
   {  
    if (shift < 0)
    {
        shift = (shift % 26) + 26;
     }
        int move = (char) ((text.charAt(0) - 'A' + shift) % 26 + 'A');
        t += move;
        i++;
        System.out.println(t);
        outFile.println(t);
        return "DONE!";
     }
                                                          // for each token listed, it expects the semi colon.
     static String caesarDecipher(String text, int shift) throws FileNotFoundException // Syntax error on token "(", "," , ")", ; expected      
     {
      return caesarEncipher(input, -shift);
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: you're missing a close brace `}` in your `caesarEncipher` method

Comment: Properly formatting your code helps you read it how the computer does (most of the time).

Answer (score 3):

Your `caesarDecipher` method definition is embedded in the method `caesarEncipher`.  That's not legal Java, and you've confused the poor compiler.

Strict indenting makes these kinds of things very clear.  If you're using an IDE, or emacs, look for tooling to re-indent your entire file (there are also command line tools under Unix):

For Eclipse: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

For Emacs: Highlight region (entire file), then: <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> OR <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

you missed the closing } on your method caesarEncipher. Use intendation to spot these errors faster.

Comment: Ok thanks, it is saying that outFile cannot be resolved. I defined outFile in my main function so all my methods can access it. Do you know what the problem may be?

Comment: if you declare a variable (like outFile) in java inside a method its scope is limited to the method. Inside another method you cannot access these local variables - you have to pass them as a parameter or declare them in another, broader scope e.g. as static class member if you wan't to use them in static methods.

Comment: How would you suggest that I declare my variable outFile. I want to print it out in the end with the newly shifted text

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `}` in the end of your

```
static String caesarEncipher(String text ,int shift) throws FileNotFoundException
```

and you have an extra one in the end of

```
static String caesarDecipher(String text, int shift) throws FileNotFoundException
```

also note, when you are returning in this ^ method, you're using the variable `input` which is undefined in this method. maybe you ment `text` which is your argument

Answer (score 0):

As said, you are missing a closing brace. I would recommend using a [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) to spot these mistakes. Many people prefer [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) but I personally like [Intellij](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). Eclipse is free, and the full version of intellij is not.